# Matlab quickest way to read data from the serial port

Tags: matlab

I am reading data from the serial device, single fscanf returns a 1 line of data, which takes around 0.02 to 0.05 seconds to get. And this will be in for loop, since I will need to read couple thousand of lines, so it will take almost a minute to do that.

```
for ii = 1:n % n is number of lines to read
    tic
    data_set(1, ii) = fscanf(serial1);
    toc
end
```

Is there a faster way to read data from the serial device, because a minute for couple thousand lines for me is way too slow.

In the above example, single fscanf timed by tic toc takes inbetween 0.02 to 0.05 seconds. When I read around 2000 lines, it can take almost a minute.

Comment: Have you compared `fgetl` or if taking in binary values just a straight `fread`?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I was thinking of trying it tomorrow, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: have you not found your answer yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be faster:

```
data_set = zeros(1, n);
for ii = 1:n
     data_set(1, ii) = str2num(fscanf(serial1))*[1 1i].';
end
```

Note that `str2num` works even if there are heading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Actually I just tested, fscanf is the one which takes most time. Per 1 line it can take 0.02 to 0.04 seconds to read it. So when you have 1000 lines, there's most of your half a minute.

What can I use instead of fscanf? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You mean read them first then process? I can, but I still will be reading it line by line, because 1 time calling fscanf returns only 1 line, hence it's in the for loop from 1 to n, so it's called n times. How else would I pull whole thing from the device?

Comment: Take a look at `textscan` or `importdata`

Comment: Pretty sure textscan doesn't read from serial port, and importata is completely irrelevant, I am scanning from serial port, not importing it from a file.

Comment: Oh, you're reading from serial port. No idea, then. I've never done that

Comment: ah.. I found something which MIGHT have worked, if I understood description correctly, but it's only in R2014a, and I am using R2009b. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/readasync.html